# Auto sync two git repositories

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to keep synchronize specific folders of two Github repositories(remote)?

There are two github repos : repoA and repoB.
Both repos have folder named ABC along with other unique folders.
If there is update in any file in folder ABC of repoA, I want to auto update folder ABC of repoB.

Comment: Did you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to apply git commands to specific folders only. You will need to syn the entire repos.

Best syn solution involves 'post-receive' hook. But since you cannot add hooks in github (as far as I know), then your only option is a cron job on any machine that can 'see' both repos, then create a clone for both repos in there (use --mirror option). With appropriate duration setting for the cron job, you can 'sync' both repos as follows in the cron script:

```
cd <to-repoA-clone>
git remote update
git push <repoB-url> --all
cd <to-repoB-clone>
git remote update
git push <repoA-url> --all
```

Now, if both repos modify the folder 'ABC', then the push will fail and you will need to do a merge (which can also be automated, but will still fail if there are any conflicts).

Also, if the content of two repos are entirely different except for the folder ABC, you may want to split off folder ABC into a repo by itself (search for `git filter-branch`). This will make syncing more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party but this is also possible with the service [Git-hg Mirror](https://githgmirror.com/). Disclaimer: I'm from the company behind it.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can, but you don't want to be duplicating content.

Instead, create a third repository, repoC, to store the common ABC folder. Then add it to repoA and repoB as a subdirectory using [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). `git submodule add <url-to-repoC> ABC/` in repoA and repoB. Now you have the shared contents as `ABC/` in both repositories.

Since `ABC/` remains its own repository, any changes made to `repoA/ABC/` can be pushed to repoC and then pulled by repoB. Same for `repoB/ABC/`, changes can be pushed to repoC and pulled by repoB. There's various ways to automate that, but they'll have to be outside of Git.