# Update local repo from remote git repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have project on bitbucket, which at its core use another project, that is available on github. I am running old version now of this project, that is on github and I want to update it locally in branch and push it remotely to the BitBucket repo so my coworkers can pull it and also update it. I wonder how to do this with minimun effort. The other project is quite big with a lot of folders and files, I don't want to update it file by file, because it will take me 5 hours. What is a clever way to pull the changes from the github repo to my local branch and then add, commit and push to BitBucket?

Comment: pull and push? should be two commands

Comment: Please be more specific. When you say "I want to update it locally"...update what? When you say "so coworkers can pull it and also update it"...pull and update what? The word "it" has no meaning by itself but only refers to something else. Make sure that "it" always has a clear reference. If not, take the time to clearly write out what "it" should refer. Similarly when you say "the other project", which one does this refer to Bitbucket or Github?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I synchronise two remote Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056327/how-do-i-synchronise-two-remote-git-repositories)

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102378/auto-sync-two-git-repositories

Comment: Googling "git sync two repositories" gives a million other hits which will answer your question.

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52543700/git-sync-repository-in-two-different-workspacesfolders-on-the-same-computer

Comment: I want to create local branch from the project in BitBucket and in this branch to pull changes from the repo in github which we use as core of our project, but need to be updated to latest version and then commit this chages in my local branch and push the branch to BitBucket repo.